# Carregar uma lista em json no JS

Tags: javascript, json, lista

Gostaria de carregar uma lista do meu arquivo JSON para usar no meu JavaScript ,
para usar o console.table() com as informações fornecidas ,

Esse é o código meu do JavaScript :

```js
fetch("infos.json") // especifique o caminho
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.table(json))
```

E esse é o do JSON :

```
{"Jogadores":[{"Jogador":"Player1","Pontuação":"15 pnts"},{"Jogador":"Player2","Pontuação":"12,3 pnts"},{"Jogador":"Player3","Pontuação":"11,6 pnts"},{"Jogador":"Player4","Pontuação":"11,2 pnts"}]}
```

[image: ScreenShot Do Erro No console e a visualização do json no Firefox]

Comment: Qual o erro que está gerando?

Comment: Desculpe agor fui ver tem um erro de caracteres no JSON !

Comment: Sou novo em progamação

Comment: Erro no JSON : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 10 of the JSON data .

Comment: Adicione o erro diretamente na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta executar um fetch

```
fetch("dados.json") // especifique o caminho
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.table(json))
```

@EDIT agora que vi o erro de sintaxe. De qualquer forma, fica a sugestão de se usar o fetch :)